# Title on the current image wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media

I want to show the specific title of the images from media library, and I have this code but the code only shows the title of the first image and not the current image being posted please help,here is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

     $the_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );

  }
}
    $output = sprintf(
        '<img%4$s src="%1$s" alt="%2$s" class="et-waypoint et_pb_image%3$s%5$s" title="'.$the_title.'"/>',
        esc_attr( $src ),
        esc_attr( $alt ),
                esc_attr( " et_pb_animation_{$animation}" ),
        ( '' !== $module_id ? sprintf( ' id="%1$s"', esc_attr( $module_id ) ) : '' ),
        ( '' !== $module_class ? sprintf( ' %1$s', esc_attr( $module_class ) ) : '' )
    );?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're code is wrong.

In the 'foreach' you're looping every `attachment`but you're always overriding $the _title.

Imagine, you have the attachments `A`, `B` and `C`, your `foreach`is looping over the array `attachment`.

1. The first element would be `A`, you save the title of `A` to `$the_title`
2. The second element would be `B`, you save the title of `B` to `$the_title`, you're overriding the value of A's title
3. The third element would be `C`, you save the title of `C` to `$the_title`, you're overriding the value of B's title

Is the `forloop` done, the variable `the_title`is holding the last `attachment`'s title.

Then you start to work with the value.

**Your Solution** is to use `the_title` within the `forloop`.

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
  if ( $attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

         $the_title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
         /*Use the title*/
         echo $the_title;

    }
  }
```

Comment: hai Robin thank you for your attention but I would like to ask what do you mean to use the_title within the forloop? I am aiming to have an output of getting the image title from media library on the current image posted but that code could only output the first image from media library.help

Comment: You re using the title outside the for loop at your output variable put that whole part in the forloop